# How to condition a cell on the response of multiple dropdown cells

Tags: conditional-formatting

I have multiple drop down cells relating to space available : cell 1 : length, cell 2 : width and a third one related to flateness.

I would like the options to make a cell green or red depending on the 3 responses from the drop down menu essentially confirming or denying if there one can deploy tents in a zone...

Is this possible on excel/google sheets?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Questions should be specific and about using a web application. It could be argued that Excel is nowadays a cross-platform app, but not all Excel apps support all the desktop app features. Questions that are specific about installable Excel apps are off-topic here. If you focus the question on a web app, it still needs work to make it a good fit because it doesn't include enough details.